# Trying to figure out how to insert initials + surname in alias for Exchange user with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Previously my script asked what the preferred username will be. Now I want to generate the username based on initials and surname.

However the alias for the e-mail is a bit different and that's the part where it doesn't work as I want to.

When an user has three initials the alias will be set to: `jh.d.smith@domain.com`, instead of `jhd.smith@domain.com`.

I don't know how to set this the proper way. Tried different methods.

```
$IMsg = 'Please enter initials' 
$Initials = '{0}.' -f ((Read-Host -Prompt $IMsg).ToUpper().ToCharArray() -join '.')

$Firstname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter firstname'
$Firstname = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase($Firstname.tolower())

$Lastname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter surname'
$Lastname = $Lastname.ToLower() -replace ($Lastname.split(' ')[-1]), (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase(($Lastname.split(' ')[-1]))

$UserID = $Initials.Replace('.','') + $lastname ## The username has to be without a dot, for example: jhdsmith.

$aliasid      = $UserID.Insert(2,'.') ## This is for the e-mail alias.
Enable-Mailbox -Identity "$UserID@int.domain.com" -Alias $AliasID -Database DOMAIN-MAIL\DOMAIN-Store\Maildatabase01 | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to do the following at the alias part:

```
$aliasid = $Initials.Replace('.','') + "." + $Lastname
```

I would also trim spaces like the following, in case someone has a lastname with spaces etc:

```
$UserID = (($Initials.Replace('.','') + $lastname).replace(" ","")).ToLower() ## The username has to be without a dot, for example: jhdsmith.

$aliasid = (($Initials.Replace('.','') + "." + $Lastname).Replace(" ","")).ToLower() ## This is for the e-mail alias.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond what you were after, but hopefully will be a good learning exercise :) If you deal with things logically, you don't need to use `Replace()`, `ToCharArray()` or `Split()`...

Starting point here is by ensuring that you input variables are all lowercase, alpha chars (`a-z` only), this can be achieved like this:

```
$Initials_input = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter initials').tolower() -replace "\W"
```

The special bit here is `-replace "\W"` this uses [regex word-characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions#word-characters) to remove any non-word character (numbers/spaces/special chars) leaving only `A-Z` or `a-z`.

Then to make it easy to convert to TitleCase or UpperCase later on I have also used `.tolower()`.

---

Once you know the state of all your inputs, you can simply build the strings to your desired format and convert to the required case.

Note that I don't change the input variables, they stay as-is. This way they are a known quantity, and you don't need to undo changes that are required by one variable to create another:

```
$Initials_input = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter initials').tolower() -replace "\W"
$Firstname_input = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter firstname').tolower() -replace "\W"
$Lastname_input = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter surname').tolower() -replace "\W"

$Firstname = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase($Firstname_input)
$Lastname = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase($Lastname_input)
$Initials = $Initials_input.ToUpper()
$UserID = $Initials_input + $Lastname_input
$AliasID = $Initials_input + '.' + $Lastname_input
```

As you can see there's much less code, and it's easy to see what format your outputs will be.

---

Example input:

```
$Initials_input = 'jxz'
$Firstname_input = 'john'
$Lastname_input = 'smith'
```

Gives outputs:

- $Firstname = `John`
- $Lastname = `Smith`
- $Initials = `JXZ`
- $UserID = `jxzsmith`
- $AliasID = `jxz.smith`

Comment: Thank you for your time to write this, however I think the first solution fits my needs. The three char initials is not working as expected, see your example: `$AliasID = jx.z.smith` this has to be **jxz.smith**

Comment: Sorry, copied from wrong tab. Now edited to correct code.